# Why does Parallelism affect if my query is successful?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Had a strange issue this week where a query failed for the first time.  It's part of a stored procedure and this is where it failed. (ive changed the fields to something generic)

Query is

```
SELECT 
p.Type, 
CAST(c.Comment AS int) AS NumberOfComments
FROM Comments c
JOIN Pages p ON c.Id = p.Id
WHERE c.CommentNo = 5 AND p.Type IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
```

The error message was

> **Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Test Text In here' to data type int.**

Using the usual order of execution I would have expected the WHERE to execute before the SELECT CAST but this didn't happen in this situation.  After the Clustered Index Scan of the Comments table there was a Compute Scalar where it did the Cast, then it did a Hash Match against the Pages Table.

The comment field isn't just used for a number, but all the comments for these specific types are always numbers.  We fixed it by using TRY_CAST instead of CAST but I also noticed that the query itself had gone parallel.

When I added OPTION (MAXDOP 1) then the query ran successfully.  The execution plan was the same except for the Parallelism so it used a similar plan.

So I guess my question is why did Parallelism cause this query to fail?

Comment: The order of execution describes things on a logical level, not on a query plan level. The optimizer feels free to rearrange things as it sees fit, so it may well happen that an expression in the `SELECT` is calculated before the `WHERE` is applied, and this becomes more likely if the plan is parallel. A T-SQL expression must be valid when applied to all data, regardless of filters, or else you risk this kind of problem. (The SQL engineers consider this a performance feature, not a bug.) As you already have found out, use `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT` to avoid this problem.

Comment: As you can see the best solution is to always test the data is valid. Have you checked the execution plan to see why the optimizer is choosing a parallel plan? Hopefully you have an index on CommentNo, and you have increased the default cost threshold for parallelism from it's default 5

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JeroenMostert, that's a great explanation. I was more curious as to why the behaviour happened and also why now.  I think the cost of the query went above the Cost Threshold for the first time which is why we then got the issue.

Comment: Thanks @sTTu, the data is legacy and its not something I can change.  The cost of the query went above the Cost Threshold so I can see why it chose a Parallel plan, I was just more curious as to why it failed when it went parallel as opposed to serial.  

I did lots of tests around changing MaxDOP, Cost Threshold to replicate the issue and then fix.  Changing these settings were not an option and using TRY_CAST resolved the issue.

Comment: Can you upload the two execution plans to "PasteThePlan" and edit your question.

Comment: I could upload images of the plans @MJH but not the actual plans.  I've amended the table names to make it generic

Comment: There is an option on PasteThePlan to obscure your table names, images of execution plans are totally useless tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query language, which SQL is, has nothing to see with a procedural language.
In procedural language, you control the order of each instruction by sequencing the pieces of the code in ordering each parts. This is known as the "how" code...
In a query language, you only specify the "what" code, not the how, and the query is translated into differents sequences of instructions (how code) to do your request, then each different solution to solve your demand are evaluated in terms of cost and finally the optimizer choose the best one that will be executed.

Sometime, the how code is changed because of subtile differences in the query, the session execution parameters, the distribution of the data values...

So you must never presume that a query will be executed the same way ever. You need to secure your query by a logic that eliminate misinterpretation...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The execution plans were identical for both Serial and Parallel (minus the parallelism steps) so i'm still not sure why it was successful when serial but threw the error when parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have values of `c.Comment` that are not numbers.  So, the conversion fails.  *This can happen even when the rows are filtered out in the `WHERE` clause.*

Further, subqueries, CTEs, and views do not help.  Why not?  Because the SQL optimizer can rearrange the processing.  In this case, it can decide to "push" the conversion closer to the data source, before filtering the rows.

Microsoft does *not* consider this a bug (in fact, it is an "optimization feature"), although I consider it a bug.  But there is a very simple way to fix it using `TRY_CAST()`:

```
SELECT p.Type, 
       TRY_CAST(c.Comment AS int) AS NumberOfComments
FROM Comments c JOIN
     Pages p
     ON c.Id = p.Id
WHERE c.CommentNo = 5 AND p.Type IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gordon, you'll see in my post that I mentioned the way we fixed it was by using TRY_CAST.  

We knew the reason it failed was due to there being non numeric data in the column, what the question was more around was why was it successful when serial and failed when parallel

Comment: Should also mention that both plans were identical (serial and parallel) with the exception of the Parallelism  repartition streams.